# Laravel 6 multiple database authentication problem

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel

I have two DB connection as bellow:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sales_report
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=192.168.102.11
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=Some_Name
DB_USERNAME=XXXXXX
DB_PASSWORD=XXXXXX
```

I am authenticating with mysql also written code as bellow:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $connection = 'mysql';
```

All DB connections are ok but still it takes too long time to login. It also does not show any result. Could you please help?

Comment: is there any error msg?

Comment: You configure multiple connections in your [`config/database.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php) file. If you write your `.env` file like you have you are only overriding one set of config with another. You need to use different entry names if you want to use multiple different configurations

Comment: No there is no error message. It just shows loading. If I remove second connection, it works fine.

Comment: @apokryfos - As connections are between mysql and MS SQL. So connection  name are different by default in Laravel 6

Comment: But you have conficting entries in your `.env` file

Comment: your env db configuration key_name is the same, it seems laravel choose the second connection, so it cannot find the connection `mysql`

Comment: change another key name will be ok.

Comment: Thanks TsaiKoga and apokryfos for your answers.

Comment: Looks like I confused you. I edited the question for connection. The IP address are different and also credentials.

Comment: @Tanvir the value is different, but you can see, the key `DB_HOST` is the same, so in your User model, connection is mysql, I think your config is `'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
 'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),`, then it will find the `DB_HOST=192.168.102.11` instead of `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`, the first host is covered by second.

Comment: @TsaiKoga - Thanks once again. But 127.0.0.1 (localhost) and 192.168.102.11 (remote host) are two different IP.

Comment: Also 127.0.0.1 - mysql but 192.168.102.11 is not mysql. 192.168.102.11 is MS SQL(microsoft)

Comment: @Tanvir you can test it in tinker:`config('database.connections.mysql')` and see the result.

Comment: Thanks both of you for the awesome help. Could you please give me up vote for the question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your env db configuration key_name is the same,

It seems laravel choose the second connection, so it cannot find the connection mysql. The first connection is covered by second.

Change another connection key name for `.env`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sales_report
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_SRV_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_SRV_HOST=Host_name
DB_SRV_PORT=1433
DB_SRV_DATABASE=DB_name
DB_SRV_USERNAME=user
DB_SRV_PASSWORD=password
```

In your config/database.php

```php
        'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            ...
        ],
        'sql_srv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_SRV_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_SRV_PORT', '3306'),
```

You can check the connection configuration in your tinker:

```sh
config('database.connections.mysql')
```

If it still not work, you can clear the config cache:

```sh
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `.env` file to:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=sales_report
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB2_HOST=Host_name
DB2_PORT=1433
DB2_DATABASE=DB_name
DB2_USERNAME=user
DB2_PASSWORD=password
```

Then in your `config/database.php` change the SQL server configuration to use the new names:

```
...
 'connections' => [
        // ... 
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],       
        // ...
        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',

            'host' => env('DB2_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB2_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB2_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB2_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB2_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],

    ],
...
```

Doing this will set the default database to `mysql` but you can use the alternative connection in each model or on the query builder:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
```

or

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('users')->...
```

You can change the default by changing the `DB_CONNECTION` entry in your `.env` file but then you need to override the connection to `mysql` where needed.